# Font Awesome not loading

Tags: asp.net, css, razor, fonts, font-awesome

I am just getting started with [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) and I must be doing something wrong with referencing files in the package. Icons are not showing up with `<i class="icon-music"></i>` for example.

The following is the default css except that I changed the file path to adhere my structure.

```
@font-face {
  src: url('../Font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
  src: url('../Font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../Font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'), url('../Font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'), url('../Font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
}
```

Relative path should be correct with all the font types inside `Font` folder and this folder sits on the same level with `Content`folder that has the stylesheet.

[image]

Is the query string appended to font names in the stylesheet for checking browsers? If so, what I done on html page with ie7 conditional comment should be invalid.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/font-awesome.css")" />
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/font-awesome-ie7.css")" />
<![endif]-->
```

Should I remove the query string after the font names in the stylesheet and keep the ie7 conditional statement instead or vice versa? or is it something else that you see causing problem?

Comment: There is some weirdness related to web fonts and IIS that might be part of it: http://sebduggan.com/blog/serving-web-fonts-from-iis/

Comment: I see you're using ASP.NET with Razor syntax. Next time, please tag your post accordingly, otherwise someone seeing the `href="@Url.Content(...)"` might not understand that syntax.

Comment: Also: Make sure your IIS instance is set up to deliver the web fonts. Try navigating to the URL directly, and see if your browser downloads/accepts the file (or attempts to display it). If you get an IIS error, you will need to set up (I believe it's) MIME types for that file, so IIS knows how to serve it to the browser.

Comment: @SpikeX Thanks for pointing out and editing accordingly. First I thought the problem may be applicable throughout in general but then I just tried and saw it working fine in other platform. As you said, this problem is `.NET` specific with IIS.

Answer (score -1):

**Your code for the html is not correct this is the right code**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="~/Content/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" />
```